# what does DetailedState.VERIFYING_POOR_LINK stand for

Tags: java, android

In Juice, the enum DetailedState adds a new state named

```
/** Link has poor connectivity. */
        VERIFYING_POOR_LINK
```

but what is this state stand for?

Having searched for the entire project, I found this:

The subclass VerifyingLinkState in WifiStateMachine.java

```
class VerifyingLinkState extends State {
    @Override
    public void enter() {
        if (DBG) log(getName() + "\n");
        EventLog.writeEvent(EVENTLOG_WIFI_STATE_CHANGED, getName());
        setNetworkDetailedState(DetailedState.VERIFYING_POOR_LINK);
        mWifiConfigStore.updateStatus(mLastNetworkId, DetailedState.VERIFYING_POOR_LINK);
        sendNetworkStateChangeBroadcast(mLastBssid);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean processMessage(Message message) {
        switch (message.what) {
            case WifiWatchdogStateMachine.POOR_LINK_DETECTED:
                //stay here
                break;
            case WifiWatchdogStateMachine.GOOD_LINK_DETECTED:
                try {
                    mNwService.enableIpv6(mInterfaceName);
                } catch (RemoteException re) {
                    loge("Failed to enable IPv6: " + re);
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                    loge("Failed to enable IPv6: " + e);
                }

                setNetworkDetailedState(DetailedState.CONNECTED);
                mWifiConfigStore.updateStatus(mLastNetworkId, DetailedState.CONNECTED);
                sendNetworkStateChangeBroadcast(mLastBssid);
                transitionTo(mConnectedState);
                break;
            default:
                return NOT_HANDLED;
        }
        return HANDLED;
    }
}
```

When it is verifying link state, in the `enter()` function, it sets the DetailedState to

```
DetailedState.VERIFYING_POOR_LINK
```

which will cause the user being confused for getting a state message like the following picture while the connection is really good. 
[image]

Although this message only stays for a while and then replaced by "Connected" swiftly. But what is this state aim for? what are the risk if I don't set the DetailedState to VERIFYING_POOR_LINK in the `enter()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`VERIFYING_POOR_LINK` for certain Samsung Devices are a part of the `Smart Network Switch` in Wi-Fi which can allow Mobile Data to remain connected over Wi-Fi if poor conditions occur.  For Samsung Devices, that's when you would see a detailed state go from `CONNECTED` to `VERIFYING_POOR_LINK`.

Most of the logic can be found in:  http://androidxref.com/4.3_r2.1/xref/frameworks/base/wifi/java/android/net/wifi/WifiWatchdogStateMachine.java

> WifiWatchdogStateMachine monitors the connection to a WiFi network. When WiFi
>   connects at L2 layer, the beacons from access point reach the device and it
>   can maintain a connection, but the application connectivity can be flaky (due
>   to bigger packet size exchange).
>
> We now monitor the quality of the last hop on WiFi using packet loss ratio as
>   an indicator to decide if the link is good enough to switch to Wi-Fi as the uplink.
>
> When WiFi is connected, the WiFi watchdog keeps sampling the RSSI and the
>   instant packet loss, and record it as per-AP loss-to-rssi statistics. When
>   the instant packet loss is higher than a threshold, the WiFi watchdog sends a
>   poor link notification to avoid WiFi connection temporarily.
>
> While WiFi is being avoided, the WiFi watchdog keep watching the RSSI to
>   bring the WiFi connection back. Once the RSSI is high enough to achieve a
>   lower packet loss, a good link detection is sent such that the WiFi
>   connection become available again.
>
> BSSID roaming has been taken into account. When user is moving across
>   multiple APs, the WiFi watchdog will detect that and keep watching the
>   currently connected AP.
>
> Power impact should be minimal since much of the measurement relies on passive statistics already being tracked at the driver and the polling is done when screen is turned on and the RSSI is in a certain range.

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't give a for sure (or guaranteed) answer..

I would say that it means that the connection is weak (Less than 30%(?) signal)

Edit:

Android offers the ability to avoid/ignore low-connectivity access points - I'm assuming that this state is suggesting that the connection shouldn't be used.

I don't see any risks in ignoring/neglecting this state.

Edit 2:

In light of recent comments, I have taken this excerpt from the android documentation:

> public static final NetworkInfo.DetailedState VERIFYING_POOR_LINK
>
> Added in API level 16 Link has poor connectivity.

It can be found at [NetworkInfo.DetailedState](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.DetailedState.html)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Actually...
He has multiple questions
The first of which, being the title - Which was my initial response.  Then I noticed more in the body so answered that in an edit.  It may not be a full answer (As was clearly stated) but it does answer the end question of "What is the risk if I don't set..."  So, clearly, I did answer his questions..  My answer, however, was vague.

Comment: "But what is this state aim for?" - "I'm assuming that this state is suggesting that the connection shouldn't be used" (In addition, "I would say that it means that the connection is weak (Less than 30%(?) signal)") ;; That's the first question within the body.  "Second question: what are the risk if I don't set the DetailedState to VERIFYING_POOR_LINK in the enter() function" got the response "I don't see any risks in ignoring/neglecting this state." So, please, tell me how it is that you figure that I neglected to give an answer.....